# Is there a DB independent way to get Db2 SQL results in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, db2, rails-activerecord

I have Rake code which I've cobbled together from some sample code in my shop, and the advice of another programmer.  It looks more or less as follows:

```
class Ticket666StupidDb2Test < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        lookup('WXYZ3529300')
    end

    def down
        puts "down, boy!"
    end

    def lookup(xiskid)
       qresult = exec_query("SELECT DISTINCT SNARK, GLOOPEE FROM VITA_XISK WHERE XISKID = '#{xiskid}'")
       while row = IBM_DB.fetch_array(qresult) do
           snark = row[0]
           gloopee = row[1]
           puts "snark = #{snark}; gloopee = #{gloopee}"
       end
    end
end
```

- Is there a way to use the result set column names in getting the data, instead of integer indices?  I looked at http://rubyibm.rubyforge.org/docs/adapter/2.5.9/doc/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/IBM_DBAdapter.html and found at least one method, `fetch_data`, which seemed as though it would allow one to reference column names, but every attempt to try to use it produced an error such as:

  ```
  rake aborted!
  undefined method `fetch_data' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::IBM_DBAdapter:0x38c16c0>
  ```
- What is wrong with this code, which was my first attempt:

  ```
  x = exec_query("Select ... blah blah blah...")
  x.each do |row|
      puts row['SNARK']
  end
  ```

  This was modeled on stuff documented at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html, but it failed with a similar exception that `x.each` is undefined.
- Regardless, the notion that I have to resort to anything like `IBM_DB.whathaveyou` strikes me as obscene.  Either IBM doesn't believe in making a standards conforming driver (not my experience using the Db2 driver for Java JDBC), or I just don't know what the supported, straightforward approach to this is.

Can someone tell me?

`ruby -v` returns `ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]`.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with `x = exec_query("Select ... blah blah blah...")`? If your query is not SQL compliant then you've tied yourself to the DBM and will have a lot more work *when* you need to migrate to some other DBM. That's the whole point of using an ORM, to separate the code from the query. It also means you'll need to stand up an instance of DB2 for development, test and production because your code can't adjust for scenarios like using SQLite for development locally, MySQL or PostgreSQL in test and DB2 in production. That's really easy with a good ORM.

Using or renaming `IBM_DB` isn't a significant issue in my experience. If you don't like calling it `IBM_DB`, assign that constant to another that is more visually pleasing. Sequel code typically uses `DB` but it's up to us what we want to call it. It's just a constant holding the connection information.

Having to index into an array is the result of using `fetch_array`. Typically, instead of using integers to identify fields, I'd define constants that are more symbolic/mnemonic and use them in place of the numbers. But, again, a good ORM makes it easy to use classes/models based on the table schema, adding layers of convenience and readability to isolate you from the uglier lower level driver's API.

Look at using Active Record or [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net). Sequel supports DB2 nicely and is easily as powerful as Active Record and works with Rails. Both also work well in a non-Rails script; Sequel is my favorite for that but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you.  This may be a semantic distinction, but as far as I understood, the derivation of my class from ActiveRecord::Migration meant that this is using ActiveRecord.  I'm certainly not coding a connection to the database - that is all happening via rake magic.  Likewise, I didn't create the name IBM_DB, so it makes me suspicious that it's non-standard. As for not using integers, the question is about using the query column names, not defining my own constants for 0, 1, ... etc.

Comment: @JerryOberle models in an ORM allow us to use the field names as accessors. That's a very nice syntactic sugar. How those are defined depends on the ORM.